# Коллекции объектов

Tags: php, ооп, коллекции

**Предисловие/вода**

У меня в проекте методы классов часто возвращают массивы данных, например, список товаров.

В таком виде:

```
$products = [ 
   "product-1" => [...], 
   "product-2" => [...] 
];
```

При работе, начал сталкиваться с разными ошибками, неудобством работы с массивом и т.д., тем более, это не соответствует методологии OOП.

Первым делом я реализовал класс, `ProductItem`.

Теперь все проще. У меня массив объектов `ProductItem`.

И метод у меня выглядит таким образом:

```
// для примера
public function getProducts() : array {
    ...
    return [
       new ProductItem(...),
       new ProductItem(...),
    ];
}
```

Возвращаемый тип метода `getProducts` - массив.
Другим разработчикам не сразу понятно, что за массив? 
Вероятно, для решения проблемы нужно создать коллекцию объектов `getProducts`.

**Вопрос**
Хотелось бы иметь возможность быстро создавать коллекции разных типов (коллекция не должна быть универсальной).

Минимальные требования к коллекции: `Iterable` и `Countable`.

Возможно, нужно создать абстрактную коллекцию, где будут реализованы `Iterable` и `Countable` интерфейсы, и описаны какие-то методы для работы с коллекцией (`get`, `has`, `delete`).

После чего, я бы смог создать свой класс `ProductItemsCollection` унаследовав от абстрактной коллекции.

И иметь готовую коллекцию объектов, в котором могли бы быть только классы типа `getProducts`, при попытке запихнуть другой объект - исключение.

Подскажите пожалуйста, может у кого-то есть готовые примеры, или кто-то поможет грамотно реализовать такое ?

Comment: недавно натыкался, похоже про то, что вы пишите, но не читал внимательно - мне не надо  - https://dev.to/drearytown/collection-objects-in-php-1cbk

Answer (score 0):

Если уж Вы почувствовали необходимость воспользоваться библиотечными / шаблонными решениями в своей работе, то, может быть, сделаете еще один небольшой "шаг вперед" - воспользуетесь одним из распространенных фреймворков, в котором эти библиотеки уже имеются, и отпадет потребность "изобретать велосипед"? (Хотя лично я тот еще любитель велосипедить... :) ) Необходимая Вам коллекция имеется, например, в [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections) и в [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Collection.html).

IMHO: [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) имеет более низкий порог вхождения и более дружелюбен к изучению "с колес", по мере необходимости. [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) же - это даже не "ящик с инструментами", это - огромная мастерская с кучей инструментов, станков и приспособлений, для правильного применения которых нужно уже достаточно много понимать и иметь опыт практического применения.

Comment: А вы про какую коллекцию в Symfony? Если вы про ArrayCollection, то он относится не к Symfony, а к Doctrine.

Comment: Constraint Collection предназначен для валидации данных, а не для их хранения.

Comment: @Undefined, не буду спорить, ибо пока еще не готов к 4 симфонии. А в 1.4, с которой пришлось плотно столкнуться по работе, не было доктрины. Я пока еще на ларе, доктрина и симфони в планах на осень.

Comment: В Symfony 4 тоже уже нет Doctrine. Всё необходимое для проекта подключаете отдельно сами.

Comment: В курсе. Но уж если задействовать всю мощь этого "завода по производству всего на свете", то не с Eloquent'ом же? Для относительно простых решений вплоть до управления распределенными системами с интеграцией платежных систем и банка лара идеальна. Symfony + Doctrine же нужен для чего-то большего, для hard Enterprise в расчете на десятилетия эксплуатации и не "монолитного". К чему и иду потихоньку. IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

> Другим разработчикам не сразу понятно, что за массив? Вероятно, для
>   решения проблемы нужно создать коллекцию объектов getProducts.

Поскольку PHP язык слабо типизированный, то решении проблемы - это PHPDoc.
Указать возвращаемый тип в комментарии:

```
/**
 * @return ProductItem[]
 */
```

Не вижу смысла в создании отдельного класса коллекции для каждой сущности.